# If a word in a sting in a column contains a character, copy it to a particular column, otherwise all other words go in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple columns of strings, and some of the words in the string contain a particular character. If any of the words contain that character, I want that single word to be copied to a particular column, and all other words copied to another column.

Here is an example with a starting dataframe and result dataframe

Starting df

```
result = [['Cat@dog.com', 'Mr Cat', '<Mr Cat>, cat@dog.com', 0, 'dogg@dog.com' ], ['Mr cat', 'cat2@dog.com', 0, 'dog@cat.com', 'dogie@dog.com' ], ['Cat@dog.com', 'cat2@dog.com', 'cat7@dog.com', 'dog@cat.com', 'dogg@dog.com'], ['Mr cat', 'Mr Cat7', '<Mr Cat>', 0, 0 ] ]

pd.DataFrame(result).transpose()



0   1
0   Cat@dog.com Mr cat
1   Mr Cat7 cat2@dog.com
2   cat7@dog.com, <Mr Cat>  0
3   0   dog@cat.com
4   dogg@dog.com    dogie@dog.com
```

Finishing df

```
result = [['Cat@dog.com', 'Mr Cat', '<Mr Cat>, cat@dog.com', 'dogg@dog.com' ], ['Mr cat', 'cat2@dog.com', 0, 'dog@cat.com', 'dogie@dog.com' ], ['Cat@dog.com', 'cat2@dog.com', 'cat7@dog.com', 'dog@cat.com', 'dogg@dog.com'], ['Mr cat', 'Mr Cat7', '<Mr Cat>', 0, 0 ] ]

pd.DataFrame(result).transpose()


0   1   2   3
0   Cat@dog.com Mr cat  Cat@dog.com Mr cat
1   Mr Cat  cat2@dog.com    cat2@dog.com    Mr Cat7
2   <Mr Cat>, cat@dog.com   0   cat7@dog.com    <Mr Cat>
3   0   dog@cat.com dog@cat.com 0
4   dogg@dog.com    dogie@dog.com   dogg@dog.com    0
```

Edit:

Some more specifications:

If none of the columns have a word that belongs in either column, just put a 0 . If multiple columns have a word that matches the criteria, anyone will do, but not multiple

In this minimal example, the character is '@'

Comment: And what is the particular character?

Comment: in the minimal example it's '@'